# Delete and recreate table in Apache Ignite

Tags: python, ignite

I am having a problem when I want to `DROP` a table and recreate it in APACHE IGNITE;
I am using a combination of REST API and PyIgnite to perform the operations.
IGNITE says the table do not exists, however it does not let me recreate it saying that it exists

```
>>> DROP_QUERY_ALERT="DROP TABLE alerts"
>>> client.sql(DROP_QUERY_ALERT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyignite/client.py", line 404, in sql
    raise SQLError(result.message)
pyignite.exceptions.SQLError: Table doesn't exist: ALERTS
>>> CREATE_ALERT_QUERY = '''CREATE TABLE storage.alerts (
...         id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
...         name VARCHAR,
...         address_field VARCHAR,
...         create_on TIMESTAMP,
...         integration VARCHAR,
...         alert VARCHAR,
...     ) WITH "CACHE_NAME=storage"'''
>>> client.sql(CREATE_ALERT_QUERY)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyignite/client.py", line 404, in sql
    raise SQLError(result.message)
pyignite.exceptions.SQLError: Table already exists: ALERTS
>>>
```

If I try to make a query, it also fails:

```
>>> N_ALERT_QUERY = '''SELECT * FROM alerts'''
>>> result = client.sql(N_ALERT_QUERY, include_field_names=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyignite/client.py", line 404, in sql
    raise SQLError(result.message)
pyignite.exceptions.SQLError: Failed to parse query. Table "ALERTS" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM alerts [42102-197]
>>>
```

I am lost since this seemed to work before, but now I am unable to continue.
Is this a bug, a known behavior? Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the ignite version?

Comment: From the rest api: {"successStatus":0,"error":null,**"response":"2.7.6"**,"sessionToken":null}

Answer (score 2):

It may be a [known behavior](https://pygridgain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#create):

> Note, however, that the cache we create can not be dropped with DDL
> command. … It should be deleted as any other key-value cache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried that, and the tables Alerts is still there: ```
>>> storage = client.get_or_create_cache('storage')
>>> storage.destroy()
>>> storage = client.get_or_create_cache('STORAGE')
>>> storage.destroy()
>>> storage = client.get_or_create_cache('ALERTS')
>>> storage.destroy()
>>> storage = client.get_or_create_cache('alerts')
>>> storage.destroy()
...
pyignite.exceptions.SQLError: Table already exists: ALERTS
>>>

Comment: Does the cache exist? It is probably named SQL_PUBLIC_ALERTS. Please check caches list with Visor CLI or REST.

Answer (score 0):

After some search and trying, I finally found that there was indeed a table by executing the following query:

`SHOW_TABLES_QUERY="SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"`

It turns out that IGNITE do not drop a table if it has at least a records, as it was in this case (http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Table-not-getting-dropped-td27957.html).

I deleted the records, and dropped the table.
It took some minutes, but then I was able to recreate the table.

Some of the confusion in my case was related to the fact that `TABLE_NAME` should have been replaced with `<cachename>.TABLE_NAME` when performing the drop query:

`DROP_QUERY_ALERT="DROP TABLE storage.alerts"`